# Can MTTF be negative?

Tags: probability

At my work I am implementing way to perform reliability calculations for few reports based on failure work orders stored in the database.

The way that they want it to be done is by performing summation of repair durations of all those work orders and divide by number of work orders to calculate MTTR. However, there is a problem with this, if selected work orders are done at the same time, or done with overlapping start and end time, summing of repair times could potentially result in negative MTTF (if MTTF is equal to MTBF - MTTR) (that is.. once summed repair time will be greater than total time used in MTBF).

So.. to clarify. Can MTTF be negative? I always thought MTBF, MTTR and MTTF can be either 0 or greater (if calculated as mean hours)

Originally I been using those formulas for MTBF, MTTR, and MTTF:

```
MTBF = TotalTime/Num.Of.Failures
MTTR = TotalDowntime/Num.Of.Failures
MTTF = MTBF - MTTR
```

where TotalDowntime is sum of downtimes which are calculated from when system is down (ignoring overlapping work orders)
example:

work orders:

```
----
   ----
   -------
```

downtime:

```
----------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$MTBF - MTBR$ is only negative if TotalDownTime exceeds TotalTime.  This would require all the devices to be down since before any were put in service, or at least that one has been down longer than it and all other devices have been in service.  These are nonsensical -- no device can be down before it is in service.  TotalTime is the total of all time, up or down, since a device is in service (and if it leaves service, you have to decide if you want to keep using its data in your statistics or not, but this is outside the scope of your question).
Notes:

- If you have three devices and the uptime is one hour, you have three hours of TotalTime.
- If you have three devices and they all experience one hour of simultaneous downtime, you have three hours of DownTime.
- TotalDownTime can never exceed TotalTime since time down is only a part of all time since being placed in service.

Comment: Does sequential or parallel repair of failures factors into reliability formulas? Since if problems are fixed in parallel fashion, total time would be shorter, versus total time when problems are fixed in sequential fashion. Or does method of how fast repairs are done do not factor in?

Comment: Each device may be considered to have its own constantly running TotalTime clock and an occasionally running TotalTimeDown clock.  These are averaged together to give mean behaviours.  Parallel repair matters when more than one TotalTimeDown clock is running and not at all when zero or one are running.  Faster repairs will result in less TotalTimeDown in either case (but by different amounts, since when two devices are down at once, the delayed repair device's TotalTimeDown clock will run longer than if parallel repair were performed).